# How to generate WSDL from SOAP message sample

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

I need to call some Web Services, but there's no WSDL for it. (I'm using Java)
For now, I'm building the SOAP message manually using javax.xml.soap classes... but that's not very clean...
What I would like to know... is there a way to generate a WSDL file based on the content of a SOAP message (sample) ? Then I would be able to use CXF...
Thanks.

Comment: I have developed several clients that consume web services in both Java and .NET and I have always used the WSDL of the web service to genereate the client with.  The WSDL describes how clients are intended to interact with the described service.  Is there NO way for you to get the WSDL?

Comment: `is there a way to generate a WSDL file based on the content of a SOAP message (sample) ?`. There are no tools but seems there are some ways to ease the manual writing of the WSDL. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264048/generate-wsdl-for-existing-soap-service-using-captured-traffic)!