# How to prepare web service and its classes based on example soap message

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services, soap

I got an example soap message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/ xmlns:web="http://com.theirdomain/webservice">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:Transaction>
         <web:ID>123</web:ID>
         <web:order>221x</web:order>
         <web:trans>112-ax-21</web:trans>
         <web:date>2013-01-01</web:date>
         <web:title>Example title</web:title>
         <web:amount>
            <web:value>10.05</web:value>
            <web:currency>USD</web:currency>
         </web:amount>
         <web:status>status</web:status>
         <web:customer>
            <web:address>Berlin</web:address>
            <web:account>12345678901234567890123456</web:account>
         </web:cusweb:customeromerData>
         <web:docHash>HASHMD5</web:docHash>
      </web:Transaction>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need a tool or a way to quickly create a classic ASP.NET XML WebService with method NewTransaction which accepts a Transaction object. I would like to know if there is a way to quickly create class (or classes) that reflect the given soap. In the result my webservice address will be given to the other company from which they will generate WSDL and they want to call NewTransaction method with Transaction object defined in WSDL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [generate a WSDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264048/generate-wsdl-for-existing-soap-service-using-captured-traffic) and then [generate a service and datacontracts from that WSDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950150/how-to-use-a-wsdl-file-to-create-a-wcf-service-not-make-a-call).

It seems to be easier to just type the few properties and the single method you have in there in a new WCF Service project and fire it up. It's SOAP 1.1 so use `basicHttpBinding`.